# can't load images in Image View using glide

Tags: android, gridview, android-glide

I'm using glide library in order to show images in Grid view, but there is noting shown in my image view. and I got an error that :

> E/Glide: class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
>   to load resource

my code works correctly as I use bitmap. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
        public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.e("sara" , "this part takes time");


            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridsq, parent, false);
            iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            file = new File(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath());
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Glide
                    .with(Gallery2.this)
                    .load(imageUri)
                    .into(iv);


            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: try to give file path instead of uri

Comment: @RahimRahimli the result is the same as uri :(

Comment: Please log this line `Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath()` to ensure it returns the correct path.

Comment: Where are your images saved? is it local or on server?

Comment: @kapsym it is local :)

Comment: instead of passing uri pass the file directly.

Comment: @sara replace imageUri with file. Glide
                    .with(Gallery2.this)
                    .load(file)
                    .into(iv);

Comment: show which path does `file` return. I think that it is incorrect.

Comment: @Safa It is "/myfiles.db/1502189610359.jpg" inside it which is correct :(

Comment: If you are using Uri, the path ahs to be in the format "file:///"

Comment: @sara in your case i suggest using file directly as your URI doesn't conform to the path followed by glide. See if using the file directly works

Comment: @kapsym it is exactly in this format :(

Comment: So what happens if you use file directly? @sara

Comment: your path is incorrect. It should be absolute path to your file something like /sdcard/appname/myfiles.db/image.jpg

Comment: @kapsym the same problem !

Comment: @RahimRahimli yes but I am developing with a platform called IOcipher which is a virtual encrypted disk and the path is in this format !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regard to Glide on Github see this [issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2110) may help you.